# How can I split time series into contiguous subsets of fixed length based on categorical values?

Tags: python, split, time-series, conditional-statements

I have a stacked LSTM network with two time series as input. One of these is categorical with four categories `mode = [0,1,2,3]`.
I want to convert this into four LSTM networks with only one input variable.
The input needs to be split into the categories. All sequences should have the length of `lookback` and sequences with mixed categories should be skipped.

For the test I created this sequence generator:

```
import numpy as np

# --- create a sequence for testing the algorithm
N = 40

mode = np.zeros(N)
mode[0] = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3])
for i in range(N):
    step = np.random.choice([-1,0,1], p=[0.2,0.6,0.2])
    mode[i] = max(min(mode[i-1]+step,3),0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below algorithm is reliable up to a `lookback < 10` (10**mode). It fills `stacks` so that `stacks[0]` holds all sequences with a `mode = 0`:

```
# --- assign common mode sequence to corresponding stack
lookback = 4    # length of the LSTM

# calculate the rolling mean of 10**mode (avoid ambiguity/mode should be int)
select = (np.convolve(10**mode, np.ones(lookback))/lookback)
select = select[lookback-1:-lookback+1]     # remove convolutional artifacts
stacks = [[],[],[],[]]                      # four different stacks, one per mode

values = list(range(N))                     # for this test a value range is used
for i in range(len(select)):
     if  (select[i] ==    1): stacks[0].append(values[i:i+lookback])  # mode = 0
     elif(select[i] ==   10): stacks[1].append(values[i:i+lookback])  # mode = 1
     elif(select[i] ==  100): stacks[2].append(values[i:i+lookback])  # mode = 2
     elif(select[i] == 1000): stacks[3].append(values[i:i+lookback])  # mode = 3

print(mode)
print(stacks)
```